# set multiple color to single line lineMarkSeries Graph in react-vis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, react-vis, lineseries

For My react Application, I need to create a line series graph with each point with a mark and color of the line should be changed when the x,y value progressing.

I have used `react-vis` plugin for that and it will display the graph with nice curves and marks. But the issue I am facing is not able to change the color of the line as the value progressing. Below is the output so far,

[image]

Someone, please tell how we can achieve this using react-vis. I have attached the sandbox link here for reference.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/line-mark-series-jsbnr):